# "mspdb100.dll" missing in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Can't get Codeblocks 10.05 working. Keep getting the "mspdb100.dll is missing" when I try to build and compile.

I have set "Selected Compiler" to VS 2005/2008. 
On my PC, I have VS Express 2010 C++ installed and working fine. 
In Codeblocks, I set toolchain executables to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\" for "Compilers installation directory".
I've also added the location of my source files to "Additional paths".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

when I had this problem reinstalling MSVC2010 didn't help but installing MSVC2010 SP1 did the trick. I hope this helps.